# Password protect website

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, passwords, ip

I'm trying to password protect my website from one ip address. 
 I just want to restrict an ip from accessing my website, but still allow them to access it if they have the password.

Comment: what you tried peter?

Comment: the .htpasswd, but it doesn't work right

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy any
```

NGINX :

```
  location / {
    satisfy any;
    allow  127.0.0.1;
    deny   all;
    auth_basic            "Login";
    auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/.htpasswd;
  }
```

Comment: for the .htpasswd would this website work? http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: Normally, yes !
Next time, post your answer on serverfault.com or use apache and htpasswd tag. Javascript and HTML aren't appropriate. :)

Comment: i want an ip to get the message and allow everyone else to access it. The code above doesn't allow me to switch it out

Comment: `AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from 1.1.1.1
Allow from all
Satisfy any`

Comment: Yes. I'm getting spam from kids on the ip. But I also work from that ip, so I need access to it

Comment: Yes, with the code you placed in the comment it should work !

Answer (score 1):

Have these 2 files in the root itself -

**.htaccess file**

```
  AuthType Basic  
  AuthName "restricted area"  
  AuthUserFile /path/to/the/directory/you/are/trying/to/protect/.htpasswd  
  require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd file**

```
  rohan:ra8i3s2YJemdM
```

*Note: One username and password per line, separated by a colon. Notice the password is encrypted. You will need to use a special tool to encrypt your password in this way (MD5). You can check David Walsh's tool here
https://davidwalsh.name/web-development-tools*